# How to show data in horizontal direction using JSF dataTable

Tags: jsf

How to display data in horizontal direction like:

```
lable: data
name: srinu
```

in multiple rows using `h:dataTable` in JSF? Right now I'm getting data in vertical direction like:

```
| lable | data|
  data   srinu
```

I want it in this format:

```
lable: data
name: srinu
```

Code which I used is:

```
<h:dataTable id="fundInfo" value="#{clientFundInfo}" border="1"
     var="client" first="0" rows="5" rules="all">
 <h:column> 
     <h:outputText value="CLIENT:"/>
   <h:outputText value="#{client.clientName}"></h:outputText>
 </h:column>
 <h:column> <h:outputText value="FUND:"/>
  <h:outputText value="#{client.fundName}"></h:outputText>
 </h:column>
 <h:column> 
  <h:outputText value="Employer Identification Number:"/>
  <h:outputText value="#{client.empIdentificationNum}"></h:outputText>
 </h:column>
 <h:column><h:outputText value="FISCAL YEAR ENDED:"/>
  <h:outputText value="#{client.fye}"></h:outputText>
 </h:column>
 <h:column><h:outputText value="Shares Outstanding"/>
  <h:outputText value="#{client.sharesOutstanding}"></h:outputText>
  </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want it to be a table, then simply use (facelets):

```
<ui:repeat value="#{clientFundInfo}" var="info">
   // feel free to use any tags here
</ui:repeat>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is not too late.

```
<table><tr>
                    <ui:repeat
                            value="#{ListOfColumns}"
                                var="columnName">

                                <td><h:dataTable
                                        value="#{ListofData}"
                                        var="Data">
                                        <h:column>
                                        <f:facet name="header">#{ColumnName}</f:facet>
                                        <h:outputText"
                                            value="#{Data.somethig)}">

                                        </h:outputText>
                                        <h:outputText"
                                            value="#{Data.somethingElse}">

                                        </h:outputText>
                                        </h:column>
                                    </h:dataTable>

                                </td>
                            </ui:repeat>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

Comment: what does ui stands for here. Is it supported in JSF 1.x ?

Comment: @Krsna Chaitanya:
I think it was not supported before v2.0 since it is part of Facelets